# Amend the current print area to remove the first column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In an Excel WorkBook I have several WorkSheets, each containing some sensitive data and a single table (ListObject).  When printing, only the table should be in the print area.

To achieve this (and to set other printing defaults) I make use of the `Workbook_BeforePrint` event.  I have two `subs` that set the value of `WS` to the current WorkSheet and `Table` to the first ListObject.

However, I have one table from which I cannot print the first column.  I'm able to target the worksheet/table, but I don't know how to strip out the first column from a print area?

```
.PrintArea = Table.Range.Address
If WS.Name = "FileNameLength" Then
    { remove the frist column from the print area }
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further code I can't tailor it but you should be able to adapt the following...

```
Sub StripFirstCol()

    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim PrintRng As Range: Set PrintRng = tbl.Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws.PageSetup
        If ws.Name = "FileNameLength" Then
            .PrintArea = Intersect(PrintRng, PrintRng.Offset(0, 1)).Address
        Else
            .PrintArea = PrintRng.Address
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, I'd not thought about it that way. Thanks for posting :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to minus the cells in the first column from the print range.

Something like this should start you off:

```
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range

    Set rng1 = Table.Range
    Set rng2 = Range("Table1[[#Headers],[columnheadertext]]")

    Set rng3 = Nothing

    For Each aCell In rng1

        If Intersect(aCell, rng2) Is Nothing Then
            If rng3 Is Nothing Then
                Set rng3 = aCell
            Else
            Set     rng3 = Union(rng3, aCell)
            End If
        End If

    Next aCell

'rng3 is your new range to be printed

 .PrintArea = rng3
```

Comment: Looping thorugh all cells in a range is a major overhead, particularly when you have 60,000 + rows in that range.  Therefore this is not for me, but thanks for posting.

Comment: I much prefer the other answer!